# Excel VBA - Call macro to clear status bar after a few seconds

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to call a macro to clear the status bar after the execution of a different macro. I realize that I can simply use:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Application.StatusBar = False
```

However, what I want to do is have my original macro end by saying something as:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Macro Function Complete."
Call clearStatusBar
End Sub

Sub clearStatusBar()
'I do not want the application.wait here because it locks up the excel program. 
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Is there a way to delay the "Application.StatusBar = False" while still allowing the user to access the program?

Let me know if you need more clarity. Thanks for your help.

Comment: go to MSDN and lookup Application.OnTime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub TestClearStatusBar()
    Application.StatusBar = "Testing: ClearStatusBar"
    ClearStatusBar
End Sub

Sub ClearStatusBar(Optional ClearStatusBar As Boolean)
    If ClearStatusBar Then
        Application.StatusBar = False
        MsgBox "Cleared"
    Else
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "'ClearStatusBar True'"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorceri was able to provide me with the correct method for my request. By using the Application.OnTime method, you can call your macro on a delay without tying up the program.

```
Application.StatusBar = "Macro Function Complete."
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:07"), "clearStatusBar"
End Sub

Sub clearStatusBar()
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```